# angular2 startsWidth of undefined error

Tags: javascript, angular

Having a issue with angular2 router it seems when I click on a link with [`routerLink]="['/url']` it console gives me an error of `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`. However if I remove the `routerLink` and just put a regular `href` it works fine.

I haven't changed anything at all and this error just came out of nowhere. Could find anything in my code, so not sure whether its a dependency issue. Has anyone else had this problem?

```
<a [routerLink]="['/reserve']" class="float-shadow">
                      Reserve &amp; Collect
                    </a>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/component/login';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/component/dashboard';
import { dragulaCompoment } from '../draggable/components/drag';
import { AuthGuard } from './authguard'

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'reserve', component: dragulaCompoment, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'order', component: dragulaCompoment, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'save', component: dragulaCompoment, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'assisted', component: dragulaCompoment, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Packacge.json angular dependencies

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/`

Comment: Please post your routes and which component contains the routerLink.

Comment: This is a known issue, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9499

Comment: @AngJobs Yeah, i know / isn't the issue as it was working fine on my test server. i have exactly the same code but the one on my local machine isn't working which is weird. I have posted my route.ts above

Answer (score 0):

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent },
```

should be

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

otherwise all paths would be treated as child routes to `''`

Comment: what, how come it was working then even without the pathMatch. Will try this

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate it is working ;-) You didn't provide too much information to be sure but to me it looks like what you try to accomplish it requires it.

Comment: Oh I mentioned it in my reply to Angjobs, I've added pathMatch to the path: '' but still not working. Do I have have to add it in each route?

Comment: No, only the one with the empty path. Otherwise `/home` would try to add `DashboardComponent` to the router-outlet of `LoginComponent`. `

Comment: Hard to tell without a full repo. Can your try to reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: Yeah im trying to put it in Plnkr but my app isn't loading. https://plnkr.co/edit/ySTXu3PTd4M7OzQk0yfJ?p=preview

Comment: When you create a new file prefix the name with `app/` to get them into the `app` subdirectory. http://plnkr.co/edit/1EAWLJXJ7ZM490rFi1Br?p=preview

Comment: Oh I see, your plnkr is just showing the loading page. but yeah that's pretty much what I have in my code. The link provided above by Ang has no solution and it's a different issue. I copied my server files which is exactly the same code, but the issue is only happening on my local :/

Comment: Your plunker was incomplete. There were components referred to but they were not included. There are lot of examples that routing is working. Maybe you have a version mismatch. You could try to purge node_modules and start over.

Comment: Yeah I think that it might be a dependency issue, I have to do npm install to install all the dependencies that are in my package.json.

Comment: How can I know if there's any dependency version mismatch? I've added my current angular dependencies above

Comment: I don't know. I'm not using TS (only Dart) and don't know about that TS configuration stuff.